# Maven and Referenced Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a eclipse java project. It has external jar in Referenced Libraries. I want to use Maven. But I would like to know how to include this external jar in Maven. Is it necessary a repository?

Comment: Is the "external JAR" yours? Or is it a standard public one like Hibernate, Apache Commons, log4j, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Just check out the maven repository http://mvnrepository.com/

Then in the Pom dependencies file you will need to add whichever dependencies you find that you will need following the xml format.  Then run **mvn package** to download the updated dependencies.

Comment: It would be great to have a tool that does this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.companyname.bank</groupId>
   <artifactId>consumerBanking</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>consumerBanking</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>ldapjdk</groupId>
         <artifactId>ldapjdk</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\ldapjdk.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you have a external jar your eclipse project references, but you want to refer to the jar using Maven.

The details of the Jar are not clear, so look to see if the jar is hosted in some public repo.

You can also install the jar in your local repository :

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/jar/abc.jar -DgroupId=group -DartifactId=artifactid -Dversion=1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DlocalRepositoryPath=/path/to/local/repository`

Make sure you replace the values for the file, group, artifactid, version and local repository path.

Then it is only a matter of including this like any other jar in your dependency section in your POM